# What is a rewriting process for a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, group-presentation

*I start my PhD in Mathematics this October and I'll be working closely with presentations, so a detailed answer aimed at that level would be ideal.*

I want to understand the beginning of [Section 2.3](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1LW4s1RDRHQC&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq="In+section+2.1+we+showed+how+to+present+a+factor+group"+Magnus&source=bl&ots=WrtOb00bED&sig=WAr4w7Khn-FtpbZO003TxHh-ado&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwptyWm5bWAhUhKcAKHdxLAxkQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22In%20section%202.1%20we%20showed%20how%20to%20present%20a%20factor%20group%22%20Magnus&f=false) of *"Combinatorial Group Theory: Presentations of Groups in Terms of Generators and Relations,"* by W. Magnus *et al*. In particular, I want to understand what a rewriting process is.

### The Definition:

> [L]et $G$ be presented [by 
>   $$\langle a_1, \dots, a_n\mid R_\mu(a_\nu),\dots\rangle]$$ and let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by the words $J_i(a_\nu), \dots$. Then a *rewriting process for $H$ (with respect to the generators $J_i(a_\nu)$)* is a mapping $$\tau: U(a_\nu)\to V(s_i)$$ of words $U(a_\nu)$ which define elements of $H$, into words in the symbols $s_i$, such that the words $U(a_\nu)$ and $V(J_i(a_\nu))$ define the same element of $H$. (The symbol $s_i$ will be the generating symbol used for $J_i(a_\nu)$ in the presentation of $H$ which we shall obtain.)

I don't understand this; in particular, I don't understand the example given just after it.

### The Example.

> For example, let $G$ be the free group on $a$ and $b$, and let $H$ be the normal subgroup generated by $b$. Then $H$ is generated by $b$ and its conjugates by powers of $a$ [ . . . ]. Let $$J_k(a, b)=a^kba^{-k}.$$ A word $W(a, b)$ defines an element of $H$ if and only if the exponent sum of $W$ on $a$ is zero. Indeed, if $$U(a, b)=a^{\alpha_1}b^{\beta_1}a^{\alpha_2}b^{\beta_2}\dots a^{\alpha_r}b^{\beta_r}\tag{1}$$ has zero exponent sum on $a$, then $U(a, b)$ and $$(a^{\alpha_1}ba^{-\alpha_1})^{\beta_1}\cdot(a^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}ba^{-\alpha_1-\alpha_2})^{\beta_2}\cdot\dots\cdot (a^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\dots +\alpha_r}ba^{-\alpha_1-\alpha_2-\dots -\alpha_r})^{\beta_r}$$ define the same element of $H$. Hence the mapping $\tau$ which sends the word $(1)$ into $$s_{\alpha_1}^{\beta_1}\cdot s_{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}^{\beta_2}\cdot\dots\cdot s_{\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\dots \alpha_r}^{\beta_r}$$ is a rewriting process for $H$.

### The Problem.

Would someone explain this to me, please?

### Thoughts.

There's nothing much to add really. I suppose I get stuck when the $s_i$s are introduced both in the definition and the example. The example makes sense in that I get the conjugation bit and the zero exponent sum; I even get the substitution of the $s_i$s. What I'm struggling with is how it fits the definition and what the $s_i$s are doing.

The first sentence I don't understand starts

> Then a *rewriting process for $H\dots$*

I hope I've provided enough context for this to be on topic.

Please help.

Comment: There is a good bit of context, but what's hard to pick out is the actual Question.  "Here's some stuff, I don't understand it or the example that follows.. can someone explain it to me" is more like what you might discuss with a tutor or an advisor, and not the sort of Question especially suited to creating content for Math.SE.  We should start with understanding how the definition of a rewrite system applies to your example.  Presentations = generators + relations

Comment: I think I understand it now anyway.

Comment: @Shaun Maybe post an answer so that others in the future can see it?

Comment: You write several times that you do not understand something, but it is still not clear to me exactly what it is that you do not understand. The basic idea is that you start with a word in the generators of $G$ that  happens to lie in the subgroup $H$, and then rewrite this word as a word in generators of $H$. What is the first sentence or phrase that you written that you do not understand?

Comment: @DerekHolt I've edited the question to include the first sentence I don't understand.

Comment: Let $U(a_v)$ be a word in the generators $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ of $G$ that represents an element of $H$. Suppose that we have a set of generators $s_i$ of $H$. Then each $s_i$ can also be written as a word $J_i(a_v)$ in the $a_i$. Since $U(a_v)$ represents an element of $H$, there is a word $V(s_i)$ in the $s_i$ that represents this element. A rewriting process is a method or algorithm for calculating $V(s_i)$ from $U(a_v)$, and we can then define the rewriting map $\tau: U(a_v) \mapsto V(s_i)$. Typically, we can only find rewriting maps for certain specific generating sets $s_i$ of $H$.